# Как вывести text_field_tag для модели?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Данная форма не сохраняет `update_at` в базу

```
 <div class="hide">
      <%= text_field_tag :update_at, :value => f.object.updated_at %>
 </div>
```

Что-бы получить `update_at` в контроллере я напишу `params[:update_at]`.Как мне получить `update_at` в модели?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно пользоваться не глобальными хелперами вроде `text_field_tag`, а методами [`FormBuilder`'а для модели](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html) (который передаётся в блок методов `form_for` и `fields_for`). Методы вида `*_tag` низкоуровневые и не стоит ими пользоваться без твёрдого понимания того, что вы хотите в разметке.

В частности, его `text_field` дублирует [глобальный `text_field`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_field), кроме первого аргумента: при вызове у `FormBuilder` он не указывается, а подставляется то, что передано (или выведено из переданного) в `form_for`/`fields_for`.

Похоже, что у вас уже есть `FormBuilder` в переменной `f`, но вы просто им не воспользовались. Нужно было примерно такое:

```
<%= f.text_field :update_at, :value => f.object.updated_at %>
```

...но такой `:value` дублирует поведение по умолчанию, поэтому достаточно:

```
<%= f.text_field :update_at %>
```

---

Для понимания процесса, это же можно было сделать (но **не надо!**) следующими способами:

```
<%= text_field f.object, :update_at %>
```

```
<%= text_field_tag "#{f.object_name}[update_at]", value: f.object.update_at %>
```